# Using SQL VIEW with WHERE Clause (ERROR)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `Entry`, `User`, `Comment`. I am showing the comment count and user (sender) full name for each entry by an sql view. But when I am using a `where` clause it's giving an error.

**My SQL View is like:**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].Entry_View
    AS SELECT 
            E.Id AS [Id], 
            Convert(varchar(10), E.Date, 104) AS [Date], 
            E.Subject AS [Subject], 
            E.Content AS [Content], 
            E.Faculty AS [Faculty], 
            E.Category AS [Category],
            (U.Firstname + ' ' + U.Lastname) AS [User],
            E.Department AS [Department],
            E.ViewCount AS [View],
            E.SupportCount AS [Support],
            Count(C.Entry_Id) AS [Comment] 
        FROM (Entry E INNER JOIN User U ON U.Id = E.User_Id)
        LEFT JOIN Comment C on C.Entry_Id=E.Id 
        GROUP BY
            E.Id, E.Date, E.Subject, E.Content, 
            E.Faculty, E.Category, (U.Firstname + ' ' + U.Lastname), 
            E.Department, E.ViewCont, E.SupportCount
```

**When I am calling:** `SELECT * FROM Entry_View WHERE E.Department = 'Administration'`

**I am getting an error:** `The multi-part identifier "E.Department" could not be bound.`

I couldn't solve this problem and need help. Thanks.

Comment: Alias `E` is not defined in your `SELECT` query.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that thread.  That thread does not include a view in the problem definition.

Comment: @DanBracuk The view has absolutely nothing to do with this question though.

Comment: I think it's not duplicate. There are lots of `The multi-part identifier could not be bound` questions, but not exact solutions for my question.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the problem is that "The multi-part identifier "E.Department" could not be bound.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select E.Department AS Department....so

```
SELECT * FROM Entry_View WHERE Department = 'Administration'
```

Answer (score 2):

The aliases used in the view definition are not available when queryting the view.  So this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entry_View WHERE E.Department = 'Administration'
```

has to become this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entry_View E WHERE E.Department = 'Administration'
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entry_View WHERE Department = 'Administration'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try: `SELECT * FROM Entry_View WHERE Department = 'Administration'`